# CO detector beeping

Tags: smoke-detectors

My Co detector is beeping every 10 to 15 seconds. I changed the battery , drained the charge by pressing and holding reset for 5 seconds. After 6 to 8 hours again it starts beeping. House is newly constructed 2 years old

Comment: Where is your CO detector located in your home?

Answer (score 4):

Living in a new build doesn't mean it's not leaking CO - maybe buy another CO detector to make sure your current one isn't defective (they're ~£15 on Amazon) and, if the new one is also beeping... then you know you have a problem.

Comment: Beeping every 10 to 15 seconds does sound more like a low battery condition.  If caused by a defective detector or two defective batteries.  The batteries can be tested to see if they are low.